# Facebook approval (with screencast?)

Tags: facebook

For my running app (iOS and Android) I'm trying to use the Facebook Connect ability to register / login users. The problem is: I need user_birthday & user_location to be approved by Facebook. Therefor I need to make a screencast to get this approved.

How am I going to screencast a feature that isn't approved but needs to be recorded?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the admin of the Facebook App, you can use unapproved permissions.

Just make a Test Version of you app and login with your "Adminaccount" and make a Screencast of the Feature. After Facebook approved it you can update the Apps in the Appstores.

Comment: I am getting message as unable to verify one or more requested permission but how can i make it work because that permission i want them to approve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to prepare a screencast and reproduce the issue in the screencast with the details like with what user you are able to reproduce the issue. The issue in your case would be that you are not able to retrieve the mentioned details.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found:

We where trying a release build (Android) instead of a debug build in combination with administrator account.